# Why does F5 (Start Debugging) play all of the websites in the solution instead of just the "start up" website?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, iis-express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debugging One Website In A Solution Of Four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272270/debugging-one-website-in-a-solution-of-four)

Our solution has around 12 projects. This includes 4 websites.

1. Main website (set as the startup project)
2. Offline site
3. A widget site
4. An API site.

Why is it that when we hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to start debugging, all the MVC sites start up in IIS express?

Is there a way to say "only start the startup project" or "the defined" project?

BTW, this is our `Configuration Properties` :

[image]

Comment: Had you started the projects earlier? One thing that always tripped me up was that when debugging stops, Casini doesn't, and the sites will continue to run. Try killing Casini or rebooting.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Casinni but IISExpress (please re-read the opening post). Secondly, there was nothing 'started'. IISExpress wasn't running / had not kicked in.

Answer (score 1):

As Pablo Romeo suggested (in a duplicate Q), the trick was to search for the keyword [Visual Studio 2010 Always Start When Debugging](https://www.google.com.au/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=13&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Always%20Start%20When%20Debugging).

This led to people saying

- open up the properties window, for the ROOT of each website project.
- Turn **Always Start When Debugging** to OFF.

[image]